# How to create 2 asp.net web form applications in the same website each in different subfolder?

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating multiple small ASP.Net Web forms applications i want on my host each project of those to run in different subfolders for the root directory of my host. When i puplish each project to different subfolders of the root directory all of them dont work. The only one that works is the one at the root directory. I think this issue is related to Web.Config. I want to ask is there a way to run each application of those in different subfolder without creating other websites ??

Answer (score 0):

**IIS**

I have been doing this a lot for testing purpose before final deploy. I just host the new application in the virtual directory of the the existing website that we own.

for eg:- **www.example.com** is our site
and we have a application named xyz then url for new application will be : **www.example.com/xyz**

You have to  add a virtual directory in the root of the IIS website  and turn it into an application by right-clicking on it in the IIS management console.

Or simply you can put the website in your root website (as in your case) and then in the IIS management console convert that folder to application.

[Create and Configure Virtual Directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173(v=vs.140).aspx)

[Setting Virtual Directories as Applications in IIS](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/virtual-directory-app/)